# Why does this ADC noise calculation divide by 6?

Tags: adc, noise, snr

I'm reading an article about ADC noise from ADI:

[Seven Steps to Successful Analog-to-Digital Signal Conversion (Noise Calculation for Proper Signal Conditioning)](https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/seven-steps-to-successful-analog-to-digital-signal-conversion.html)

> Let’s assume that we have a sensor that outputs a 10 kHz signal with full-scale amplitude of 250 mV p-p (88.2 mV RMS) and 25 μV p-p noise

[image]

I don't understand the calculation method of noise, why it's divided by 6. Can anyone help to explain it?

Comment: A factor of 6 *could be* a rough conversion of *peak-to-peak* noise to *root-mean-square (RMS)* noise amplitude.

Comment: Assuming a gaussian distribution of noise, 99.8% of the noise will be contained within ± 3 standard deviations. So 25 µV peak-peak would cover 6 times the standard deviation, thus your standard deviation is approximately 4.16 µV.

Comment: @Ben That's an answer, however short.  You should post it as such.  The other one, too, but Ben's has more words (!).

Comment: @TimWescott I will!

Comment: @Ben  thank you,i find some useful info in [MT-004](https://www.analog.com/media/en/training-seminars/tutorials/MT-004.pdf),it shown P-P INPUT NOISE ≈ 6.6 × RMS NOISE.